# Exact preimage of an interesting open ball

Tags: general-topology

Consider the function $$g: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^\omega$$ given by $$g(t)=(t,t,t,...)$$ where $ \mathbb{R}^\omega$ is in the uniform topology.
Can we find the exact answer to $$g^{-1}(B_{\rho}((1-\frac{1}{2^n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}, 1))$$ where $\rho$ is the uniform metric as defined in Munkres' Topology book (page ~120))
i.e. $$\rho(x,y) = \sup_i\{ \min\{|x_i - y_i|, 1\}\}$$

I have been able to show that the pre-image is of the form $(0,1+\epsilon)$ but I can't determine the exact value of the right hand side limit.

Regards.

Comment: @Srivatsan: I suspect that the first argument is missing a pair of parentheses: $B_\rho\left(\langle 1-\frac1{2^n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\rangle,1\right)$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo, done.

Comment: @Srivatsan, the expression inside the bracket is the open ball with radius $1$ centered at the $(1-\frac{1}{2^n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, the first argument is an element in $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ which is a sequence.

Comment: Is $0$ in $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @Chris, no it is not.

Comment: @Chulumba: Yes, that’s what I thought (and wrote).

Comment: If $t>1$, $g(t)$ will be in the ball iff $|t-1/2|<1$, so ...

Comment: To elaborate @Brian's answer, if $t > 1$, then the distance between $g(t)$ and the center of the open ball is simply:
$$
\min \{1, \sup_n (t+2^{-n}-1)  \} .
$$ The expression inside the sup is maximized for $n=1$ (or whatever the starting index is). And you want this distance to be strictly smaller than $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve done the hard part in getting $0$ as the left endpoint of but not included in the inverse image. Suppose that $t>1$ and $g(t)$ is in the ball. Then certainly 
$$\min\left\{\left|t-\frac12\right|,1\right\}<1,$$ so $1<t<\frac32$; what can you say about $$\min\left\{\left|t-\frac1{2^n}\right|,1\right\}$$ for arbitrary $n\in\mathbb{N}$?